# Custom search and code issue

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Trying to do a kind of 'advanced search' I have found this code:

```
function custom_search_where($pieces) {

    // filter to select search query
    if (is_search() && !is_admin()) {

        global $wpdb;
        $custom_fields = array('ISBN','Edicion');
        $keywords = explode(' ', get_query_var('s'));
        $query = "";
        foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
             foreach ($keywords as $word) {
                 $query .= "((mypm1.meta_key = '".$field."')";
                 $query .= " AND (mypm1.meta_value  LIKE '%{$word}%')) OR ";
             }
        }

        if (!empty($query)) {
            // add to where clause
            $pieces['where'] = str_replace("(((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%", "( {$query} 

((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%", $pieces['where']);

            $pieces['join'] = $pieces['join'] . " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS mypm1 ON 

({$wpdb->posts}.ID = mypm1.post_id)";
        }
    }
    return ($pieces);
}
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'custom_search_where');
```

Works fine in the sense that show my custom fields (words and numbers, that I need) and allows me to do a crossed search: I did a custom search form where the idea is to search by editions, title, name, numbers, colections and sections. Editions are custom post type (works fine), title, name and numbers are custom fields (works fine too with this script), section and coleccion are taxonomy it display through a select (working fine)

The issue is:
If I search for a number (code from a book) show the post, only one, as normal; but if I search for a word (book title or name) it display many post (10 or more)
I'm new in wordpress and code, so I need a bit help for to solve it: what I need to change in the code for to display my search as normal (to show only one, without replicates)

I know is a lot of codes there out and I have tested, but this is one that works relatively fine with my search form, except for the replicates.

Answer (score 1):

After a while looking for, today, I have found a answer in the next link (is the same code than before but with a inclusion for to avoid any duplication)
Works fine.

http://pastebin.com/seNZYDSJ

I hope could be useful if somebody have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this solution! I had the exact same issue wich is fixed now :)